# Speech in a different language

Tags: actions-on-google

I need to change the speech language *for a specific response*. I know I can change the TTS voice for the whole app, but I have not found a way to do that for a response. In this case, the supported user locales are English and German, but the text I want Google Assistant to speak is in Korean.

Interestingly, there is no problem if the user locale is German and the text is in English. However, when I tried to create a response with Korean text, there was no audio feedback.

Comment: Hi did you find any solution to your problem. Cause I would like to use two languages in the same sentence but cannot find anything working.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Actions on Google platform does not have support for in-dialog language changes. The case you've outlined may be an exception based on certain languages having support for other-language words which are supported as a subset in the primary language.

One alternative you might consider here is using recorded spoken audio through [SSML](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml). This is a popular way to insert custom audio output into your app, which may make sense for your use case.